# Rails: automatically get associated data for each row

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, paperclip

I'm not exactly a newbie and know how to do this in PHP but in Rails my head is spinning.

I have a model Buildings

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :assets
   ...
end
```

and using the Paperclip gem as Assets model

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :buildings
  ...
end
```

I want to have assets automatically requested with buildings in a DRY way. What I'm trying to avoid is doing one query to get all user's Buildings and looping over that to get all Assets for each row (like in buildings#index). I want something like this:

```
@user.buildings.photos
```

Is this doable with associations or do I have to do an annoying custom SQL query to JOIN and make a bunch of virtual columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want multiple queries to be fired use:
`@user.buildings.includes(:assets)`

and if you are looking for all the assets of a user:
`@user.buildings.includes(:assets).collect {|building| building.assets}.flatten`

A better way would be you define assets method in User model:

```
def assets
  buildings.includes(:assets).collect {|building| building.assets}.flatten
end
```

and access `@user.assets`

Comment: Thats close but I explained it poorly: I am already using the @buildings in a loop in the view and want to be able to access assets within that array. Example: `@buildings = @user.buildings; @buildings.each do |d| {  @buildings.assets.each do |a| { ... } }` (Ignore the poor pseudocode)

Comment: From what I get you are trying to say- you want to access assets while looping buildings. In that case you don't any of the code above, and defining the associations is sufficient. Try: @buildings.each {|building| building.assets.each {|asset| # Do whatever you want to do with asset}}